# Rails (Koala): Can't login to Facebook - Load denied by X-Frame-Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, koala

I am using this code to Facebook from my Rails app using Koala:

```
  def login #login on Facebook
    session['oauth'] = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(SITE_URL+'/callback')
    # redirect to facebook to get your code
    redirect_to session['oauth'].url_for_oauth_code(:permissions=>PERMISSIONS)
  end
```

When login is executed, I get the following error message:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=MYAPPID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback
&scope=public_profile does not permit framing.
```

Seems to be trying to show the canvas for login, but my app is just a website that needs Facebook authentication. Is there anything that I have to change in my Facebook App settings or in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following into your config/application.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com'
}
```

PS: don't forget to restart your server after you add this.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I get: `Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'http://example.com/': 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.`. I already had the ALLOWALL.

Comment: OK just do a test with the following `'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'` instead `'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com'
`